# How can I connect with an external authentication server with ASP.NET Core in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate with ASP.NET Core using the Google API, to be able to access the people api.

I have the following code:

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddOpenIdConnect(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
               GoogleDefaults.DisplayName,
               options =>
               {
                   options.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
                   options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                   options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication: Google:ClientSecret"];
                   options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                   options.Scope.Add("openid");
                   options.Scope.Add("email");
                   options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
               });
```

The problem is that I get the following exception

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. HttpResponseMessage: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]', HttpResponseMessage.Content: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'

How can I solve this issue?

Second question: how can I access the access token from the controller in order to be able to send requests to the People API?

Best regards,
Mike

Comment: so you go to the link from the Exception?

Answer (score 1):

[regarding how to access the user in the controller]

Do you use JWT token? if so, i access it with:

```
this.HttpContext.User;
```

then, if you haven't modify that yet, the jwt payload is divided in several claims. In my case, by default the token is stateful(meaning that carries user information in it) and the user id was stored in the fifth claim

```
.Claims.ToList()[5].Value;
```

Comment: Hello Red,
thanks for your answer.
I don't configure a jwt token. How can i do that?

Comment: I've used a default template for SPA (single page application, mvc with react or angular), and by default is setted to token bearer authentication using jwt. Are you doing the same?

Comment: Hello @Red,
No, I'm using the a mvc razor pages technology. There, by default is no authentication implemented.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect I think is a jwt by default, try to access the HTTPContext user and see what it says in the claims field

Edit: but now i remember that you still can't make the oAuth working